# Is it possible to reference an anonymous function from within itself in PHP?

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
// assume $f is an arg to the wrapping function
$self = $this;
$func = function() use($f, $ctx, $self){

    $self->remove($func, $ctx); // I want $func to be a reference to this anon function

    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array($f, $args);
};
```

Is it possible to reference the function assigned to $func from with the same function?

Comment: Wow, I wish I could mark all of these as answers!

Comment: And I wish one of the answers would have elaborated on the reference creation and delayed assignment.

Comment: @mario and I wish you would answer yourself with the one **you** think is right, instead of complaining about the answers that people put here.

Comment: @Andrew, you can upvote all the answers you found useful.

Comment: @Neal: By "put" you mean "pasted", eh? And no, I can't answer that with certainty. Hence the question.

Comment: By the way, in languages that don't allow such reference magic there is also a technique called "Y-Combinator" that allows to do lambda recursion.

Comment: @mario Well what isn't clear about it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try doing

```
$func = function() use (/*your variables,*/ &$func) {
    var_dump($func);
    return 1;
};
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/cLd3Fu

Comment: How can we do it without having to *name* the anonymous function?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can

See this example: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#105564

---

Code from example:

```
<?php
    $fib = function($n) use(&$fib) {
        if($n == 0 || $n == 1) return 1;
        return $fib($n - 1) + $fib($n - 2);
    };

   echo $fib(2) . "\n"; // 2
   $lie = $fib;
   $fib = function(){die('error');};//rewrite $fib variable 
   echo $lie(5); // error   because $fib is referenced by closure

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible if you `use` a variable by reference. For example:

```
$func = function($i) use(&$func) {
    if ($i <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    echo "Countdown: $i.\n";
    $func($i - 1);
};

$func(3);
```